# How to make a Layla++ kernel to load a app?

Tags: load, kernel

**I tryed to make a Kernel in F.C.E. Layla language but it won't let me to create a `null_var`
after the `break_key_point1` phase.
I need a code that can load the next Layla app after first one was succesfully loaded.
 E.G.: After the "Welcome screan" comes up, I need to make the Kernel to show me a kind of desktop (The app that I allready built but I can't tie them up).
My codes for tied apps are:

```
<Layla Code 2.4
   <After. - a(kernel1.boot.room- done)
   <Load. - a(Kernel.apps.Welcome #4sec#)
   <Load. - shell(desktop.fce #00#)
  <-------rest of code-------*
```

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a null variable by assigning `NULL` to it.
Like this:

```
string name = NULL;
```

Although the question did not make much of sense, I think you want to load an app from another in C++.